# How to do a Get request from a form using ajax and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am using Node.js with the express framework for my web application. What I am trying to do is get the input from the client side (**index.js**) after a button click and request the information from my route (**app.js**) based off that parameter to display on my index page. I tried using ajax to make the request to my route but it does not work. I know I am doing something wrong with the URL Query string but not too sure how to fix it. Let me know if I need to clarify anything more. Thanks in advance.

**index.ejs**

```
<form action="" id="searchForm">
    <!-- Input box-->
    <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName">
    <!-- Submit button-->
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
// When the search Button is clicked run function
$("#searchForm").submit(function () {
    // Make a ajax request to a route
    $.ajax({
        // Connect to /json route
        url: "http://localhost:8080/json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        // If there is no errors run my function
        success: function (data) {
            //Writes the data to a table
            var table = "";
            for (var i in data) {
                table += "<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
            }
        },
        // If there is any errors, show me.
        error: function () {
            alert('Oops, there seems to be an error!');
        },
        type: "GET",
    });           
});
});
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function (app){
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs'); //load the page
    });

app.get('/json', function (req, res) {
        var SomeQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE '%" + req.query.userName+ "%';
        client.query(SomeQuery, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err; //Show any errors
            var data = [];
            // Loop through all known data
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                data.push(results.rows[i]); //Push any information into empty array
            }
            res.json(data); //send it to make an ajax request
        });
    });
});
}
```

**Solution**
For anyone who ran into the same problem here was the fix:

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
// When the search Button is clicked run function
$("#searchForm").submit(function () {
    // Make a ajax request to a route
    //Value from input
    var userNameID = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
        // Connect to /json route
        url: "http://localhost:8080/json?userName=" + userNameID,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        // If there is no errors run my function
        success: function (data) {
            //Writes the data to a table
            var table = "";
            for (var i in data) {
                table += "<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
            }
        },
        // If there is any errors, show me.
        error: function () {
            alert('Oops, there seems to be an error!');
        },
        type: "GET",
    });           
});
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're relying on `req.query.userName` but you never put that value in the query string in `script.js`.

Comment: Just like this right? (where userNameID is equal to the value of the input) `url: "http://localhost:8080/json?userName=" + userNameID`?

Comment: The format is [`<url>?name=value&otherName=otherValue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). Your example is missing the `=`.

Comment: Is important to test each side separate, i.e. if you can reach `GET http://localhost:8080/json?userName=asd` successfully (using CURL, POSTman or whatever), you can forgot node at all. 

Same goes for your jquery, you can test against a mock XHR (i.e. superspy) to check if the client-side code is doing what its supposed to do.

I think @JeremyPridemore its right

Comment: @Jeremy Pridemore I forgot to add the `=` but  tried that and no luck.

Comment: @sminutoli So I am able to get the data from my `/json` route when I add the query string to the end of it `/json/userName=carlos`. But it is on a separate page that is just json. I want to have it on the same page in some table where I did the search. If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, you have two issues here: one is the missing parameter (you can add the `'userName='+form.userName` here). 

The second is that (as was pointed in the answer below) you need to prevent the browser default behaviour using `event.preventDefault()` or returning `false`.

Comment: @carlosE. in order to get the data on the same page you're using AJAX, but what I wanted to point is that you can think client and server code as two really independent and separate things (otherwise you will enter the spaghetti realm in your mind, ;)). It's great that you can reach `/json/userName=carlos` getting a pure json page as a result, this tells you "hey, node isnt the problem"

Comment: Also, the code that you're using in the success handler here doesn't write anything out. So once you fix the issue that Sergey Avanesyan answered below (plus fixing the query string) you should be getting data back even if you don't see it. Then you'll just need to fix your writing of the table to see it.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. For some reason I couldn't wrap my head around it all too well. But I got the solution thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you use input type submit. Submit realod the page and show which back is sent. There are several way to solve it։

1. The first approach to solve it, change submit type to simple button type.
2. The second approach is stop default browser behavior using event.preventDefault()

   ```
   `$(document).ready(function () {    
   // When the search Button is clicked run function
   $("#searchForm").submit(function (event) {
     // Make a ajax request to a route
     $.ajax({
       // Connect to /json route
       url: "http://localhost:8080/json",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: 'json',
       // If there is no errors run my function
       success: function (data) {
           //Writes the data to a table
           var table = "";
           for (var i in data) {
               table += "<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
           }
       },
       // If there is any errors, show me.
       error: function () {
           alert('Oops, there seems to be an error!');
       },
       type: "GET",
     });   
     event.preventDefault()       
    });
   });`
   ```

Comment: Thank you for helping me get the solution. I got the answer by using `event.preventDefault()` and as well by adding the parameters in the URL for the query string `http://localhost:8080/json?userName=" + userName`.